# Google sheets Passing Cell Value to another sheet via clicked link on current sheet

Tags: google-sheets

So I have a Google Sheets workbook with two sheets, **Sheet A** and **Sheet B**.

On Sheet A column A I have a set of codes for example
*A1 = 101, A2 = 102, A3 = 103,* and so on...

On **Sheet B** I have assigned an empty cell "**D2**" that I use in a formula on that same sheet *(sheet B)* to load filtered data, based on this cell value, obviously equal to one of the codes on **Sheet A**.

Is it possible to have a link on **Sheet A!A1** that **opens Sheet B** and **sets D2 value to "101"**?
I understand the cells cannot pass variables, so I am really interested whether this could be done via scripting.

Your input and help is appreciated, knowing I can understand scripting and the logic behind it but I am not a programmer, so a bit of details would be welcomed.

Comment: In order for members to give you valuable feedback, please provide an example sheet and share an editable link.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [The correct way to publicly share a Google test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) and [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Answer (score 0):

Create a [drop-down list](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103) that lets you choose one of the values in `A1:A`. Refer to the drop-down list cell in the `filter()`. If the two sheets are in different spreadsheet files, use `importrange()` to copy the value.